# How to disable the color of the next row appearing in an overlayed table

Tags: beamer

I was using the following code to create a colored table with overlays. However, it shows the color of the next row with the row above. How can I avoid it?

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{red!10} 
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}\hline 
        \onslide<1->Class & A & B & C & D\\\hline
        \onslide<2->X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \onslide<3->Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        \onslide<4->Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
        \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit: This seems to work for me. But is there any reason for that?

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{red!10} 
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}\hline 
        \onslide<1->Class & A & B & C & D\onslide<2-> \\\hline
        \onslide<2->X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \onslide<3->\\
        \onslide<3->Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \onslide<4->\\
        \onslide<4->Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
        \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place `\onslide` before the `\\`.  Otherwise LaTeX will flush the row and insert a sentinel in place of `\onslide` which then appears as the first column.

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{red!10} 
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \hline 
    Class & A & B & C & D \onslide<2-> \\
    \hline
    X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \onslide<3-> \\
    Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \onslide<4-> \\
    Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```